# Atmega328p I2c to SPI

Tags: i2c, atmega328p, isp

I have atmega328p and I need resend data from more sensors I2C to another atmega328p via SPI. Do you have some example? I am only beginer.

Comment: What have you succeeded so far? Where are you blocking? If you haven't started yet, I would suggest you start by reading the I2C sensors and displaying the values in the Serial Monitor (if you use ArduinoIDE). And take some time to see if you can find a library for your sensors, it's usually simpler than to implement the communication by you self (ie looking up which registers you have to read/write)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by breaking up the problem into smaller tasks.

First, receive and buffer the data from the I2C sensors. If you are using an ATMEGA328P, then help yourself by using the Arduino bootloader and create a simple I2C sketch. So many examples out there. Send the data out the Serial port to ensure it was received properly.

Next, try sending a fixed pattern data out the first ATMEGA328P over SPI wires. Again, just make it easy and create a simple Arduino sketch. If you can, check the output from first device with a logic probe or o-scope.

Next, connect the two ATMEGA328P microcontrollers SPI ports and try receiving the fixed pattern data from the first.

Lastly, change the fixed pattern data you were sending out the SPI to the buffered data received from the I2C sensors.